# Subdivision surface modifier breaks halfway through object

Tags: subdivision-surface

Working on the Owl tutorial on Blender's YT channel. Got stuck on the wing part where it adds the Subdivision Surface modifier. For some reason the modifier only works on half of the object, and the rest remains as if it didn't have the modifier.

[image]

[image]

I double checked in the wire frame that the vertices weren't connected where they shouldn't be. The only reason I can think of that it would not be working is that I manually deleted the faces on the edges and created new faces because when subdividing the original square shape it created too many vertices on the edges.

Comment: maybe you have overlapping vertices, try a Merge By Distance

Comment: Try merge by distance, maybe you have overlapping vertices? Edit: wait whaat